# What do all of Internet Explorer's search settings mean?

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, windows-registry

System information logging tools, such as Hijack This, enumerate several parts of Internet Explorer's settings, including settings which control the way it searches. Research has led me [here](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/tutorials/how-to-use-hijackthis/#RDiag), giving these registry values:

```
${Hive}\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Search\\SearchAssistant
${Hive}\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Search\\CustomizeSearch
${Hive}\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MAIN\\Search Bar
${Hive}\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MAIN\\Search Page
${Hive}\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\\SearchURL
```

I'm trying to determine what behavior each of these different entries causes to an Internet Explorer installation, because just looking at them at a cursory level they do the same thing... Does any documentation exist explaining what the difference is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**SearchAssistant** This is a legacy setting. The Search Assistant is essentially a special web page that would load in a side bar for quick web searches. Below, the default MSN Search Assistant is loaded in the IE6 sidebar pane:

[image]

**CustomizeSearch** I *believe* this refers in some way to a toolbar to be loaded, along with the next one.

**Search Bar** I *believe* this refers in some way to a toolbar to be loaded.

**Search Page** This is a legacy setting which specifies the URL to open if the user selects `Start`->`Find`->`On The Internet`. I think this only applies to versions of Windows prior to XP.

**SearchURL**  The URL to use when the user types something into the address bar that isn't an address, for example: `http://www.bing.com/search?q=%s` where `%s` is filled by the user's query.