# How can I use Internet Explorer's SearchUrl shortcut (in the address bar)?

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, shortcuts

Internet Explorer has long had a very useful "hidden feature": a shortcut for quick searches from the address bar, allowing you to use any number of websites as search providers (as described in [an answer to *What do all of Internet Explorer's search settings mean?*](https://superuser.com/questions/388166/what-do-all-of-internet-explorers-search-settings-mean/388176#388176); the settings are stored in the registry at `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\SearchUrl`).

For example, if I associate the shortcut `"su"` with the address `"https://superuser.com/search?q=%s"`, I could type `"su Internet Explorer"` in the address bar and instantly get [this resulting page](https://superuser.com/search?q=internet%20explorer).

However, the only way to set up and maintain it (that I know of) is by editing the registry (as described in *[Windows 7 : Using Any Search Engine from the Address Bar](http://mscerts.programming4.us/windows/windows%207%20%20%20using%20any%20search%20engine%20from%20the%20address%20bar.aspx)*; archived [here](http://liveweb.archive.org/http://mscerts.programming4.us/windows/windows%207%20%20%20using%20any%20search%20engine%20from%20the%20address%20bar.aspx)), or by installing a utility like [Tweak UI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tweak_UI) (a [Windows XP powertoy](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/downloads/windows-xp) that is apparently no longer officially supported). At work I don't have administrator privileges to my workstation, so those options won't work for me. Is there another way to expose this feature?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have regedit privileges, you can still import .reg files that only touch HKCU.  Other than that, I think by default in IE8 it will use your default search provider (which you can manage with the little drop-down in the search box).

Comment: I'll have to check whether office policy permits reg file imports. As for the IE8 default search provider, that is a different functionality (quite limited by comparison).

Comment: Ah, okay, I didn't know if you were referring to that. Incidentally you can also add custom search providers though obviously it's a bit less convenient.  The old MS page is gone (sigh) but this replicates it: http://www.enhanceie.com/ie/searchbuilder.asp